# PKPushRegistryDelegate never called

Tags: swift, pushkit

I got many results when I tried with `PKPushRegistryDelegate` not called but nothing solved my issue. All are suggesting to check info.plist for background modes which is fine in my app. I enabled voip, background fetch, Remote notifications. Create VoIP certificate in apple developer account also. I wrote following lines in `didFinishLanunchingWithOptions`

```
let pushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
pushRegistry.delegate = self
pushRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [.voIP]
```

And delegate methods as below

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
    if let token = String(bytes: pushCredentials.token, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        print("Push token: \(token)")
    }
}
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("notification received")
    print(payload)
}

func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didInvalidatePushTokenFor type: PKPushType) {
    print("Token invalid")
}
```

But those delegate methods are never called. As VoIP certificate is only on production, I tried with production certificate and checked logs for push token but not found. Is there a way to debug it with development certificates? Am I missing anything here? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue in iPhone 6 with version 11.4. Tried with a different device iPhone 6+ and it worked normally. This might be an issue in some of the devices, but this is not mentioned anywhere in Apple docs.

Please use the following code in `didUpdate` delegate method:

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
        let pushToken = pushCredentials.token.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        print("voip token: \(pushToken)")
    }
```